# Convert hex to ASCII string in JS

Tags: tokens, javascript, ethers.js

I am want to get a token's name, symbol, and decimal received from `eth_call` method. For example, USDT's contract address on Avalanche is '0x9702230A8Ea53601f5cD2dc00fDBc13d4dF4A8c7'. When using `eth_call` to get the token's information, I get

```
[
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "result": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b546574686572546f6b656e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 2,
        "result": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045553447400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 3,
        "result": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006"
    }
```

So, I am trying to convert to the format I want.

```
let response = await this.bassApiProvider.getTokenData(tokenAddress)
 //if id is 3, it represents token's decimal
response = response.map(item => item.id === 3 ? utils.hex2Number(item.result) : ethers.utils.toUtf8String(item.result))
```

But What I get after `map` is

```
[
    "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000bTetherToken\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
    "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004USDt\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
    "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0006"
]
```

The result does actually includes the value I want, but also includes lot of binary...

Does any one know how removing tons of `\u0000` and keep the name and symbol and why is there lots of binary words?

Thank you!

Comment: The returned data is encoded using Contract ABI https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html

Comment: @Ismael How do I need to decode the returned data?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a library like web3js, ethers.js (or similar in your favorite language), they already do the decoding after a call returns. If you don't want to use those libraries and you need a particular function you should be able to read the abi spec and create a simple parser for your use case.